# Exporting to DirectX for Vehicle Simulator with correct axis for each object, Blender equivalent of Xform reset?

Tags: modeling

So, my problem is when I export to DirectX format (.x), it shows strange in Vehicle Simulator (a vehicular simulator), and my model does not behave as it should. the propeller of my ship, which should rotate in a clockwise way, and the rudder which should probably rotate on the Z axis (up-down). So, my problem is that in Vehicle Simulator, the axis is wrong. As when I try to apply the elements instead of the properties of the ship and it's behaviour, it's all messed up. A friend told me he used the Reset Xform function in 3ds Max to correct the axis, is there a similar feature in Blender?

Comment: Please Create another separate post for your second question. Keep it to one question per post.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to have solved this myself, somehow by tweaking the pivot points of the objects in the scene of Blender.

Comment: Even though I need to flip the entire model -90 degrees on the X axis to get everything right, and set the propellers pivot point at the opposite side (minus) of what it in fact is to get the blow from it to emit correctly...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32097)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the answer to the question. I do not know the equivalent of Xform in 3ds Max to something similar in Blender 3D. So, I'm sorry, but I don't know the answer. I have spent days trying to figure this out, to no avail. But rotating the model in the proper directions inside of Blender  seems to work.